# Qt Creator / Qt embedded widget demo

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have downloaded the source code for the embedded widget demos from Nokia's site and tried to get it to compile. I end up with the following error:

Compiler (MinGW32) message :

> In file included from
>   ../../src/basicgraph/qtbasicgraph.cpp:9:
>   ../../src/basicgraph/qtbasicgraph.h:14:17:
>   QtGui: No such file or directory

The offending line is

```
#include <QtGui>
```

Qt Creator 1.2.0, Qt 2009.03

I have checked paths, etc, and all seems fine. I have checked to make sure that I have implicitly included `QT += gui` and that I have NOT included `QT -= gui` anywhere in the `.pro` and `.pri` files.

After making no changes, I used VS2005 and the appropriate commercial version of Qt 4.4.3, and it compiled and ran fine.

I have googled the error, and have found others asking similar questions (but not here) but no posted answers... So I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Jonathan Howland

Answer (score 0):

QtGui is a meta-include file that includes all header files of the QtGui module, you should find it in the include/ folder of your Qt installation. If this isn't created, something went amiss in your install. Alternatively, you might want to check that you are using the correct qmake; qmake --version should tell you which qmake is being used.

Comment: I am familiar with the meta-include concept.  QtGui exists and is found in many other QT projects I have written myself or compiled from open source projects.  And I am pretty sure I am using the correct qmake, since I am compiling within QT-creator, and many other projects build just fine in that environment.

so I don't think this is an answer, although I appreciate the effort.  I think this problem is going to be specific to the embedded demo configuration